# Creating centered widgets Reactjs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create 3 widgets that are are equal in width and height and equal distance from each other, I understand that I must use CSS flexbox but not 100% where to start

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating a `div` with attributes `display: flex` and `flex-direction: row`. Then inside this `div`, create 3 smaller divs with your `width` and `height`, then you can use `column-gap` to create the gap between your widgets.
If you want to center your widgets, you can use the `justify-content: center` property.

Comment: How can I further modify this to allow me to add a cursor when I hover over it?

Comment: You can add `cursor: pointer` to your widget element.

Answer (score 0):

Use `justify-content` in `flex` container.

**Widgets Evenly spaced in the row.**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.widget {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ce8888;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="widget">Widget 1</div>
  <div class="widget">Widget 2</div>
  <div class="widget">Widget 3</div>
</div>
```

**Equal spaces between Widgets excluding the start and end space.**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.widget {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ce8888;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="widget">Widget 1</div>
  <div class="widget">Widget 2</div>
  <div class="widget">Widget 3</div>
</div>
```